# Promise - Call a function in between two promises

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have two requests and some function to be called in between. The flow is that when the first promise is called and finished, no matter what result is (success or failure) some non-promise related function should be called and only after we should call the second promise. So this is how I ended up doing it, which does not look like a good solution.

```js
funtionReturnsPromise()
    .then(()=>{})
    .catch(()=>{})
    .then(()=>{
        nonPromiseRelatedFuntion()
    })
    .then(()=>{
        return funtionReturnsPromise2()
    })
```

Comment: Everything in `then()` is promise related. You either have to put your code before or after the promise code. You can't put it between if you want have it unrelated to a promise.

Comment: and why do you think this is not a good solution?

Comment: I am not sure, but can't you use callback in last line of first promise?

Comment: You example wouldnt look so odd if you did something with the error - you probably want to log/handle it somehow in the "real world" and then your example becomes perfectly fine. It basically follows exactly what the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) does titled `Using and chaining the catch method`

Comment: If `nonPromiseRelatedFuntion` is asynchronous (i.e. "has a callback") and you want to wait for it in the promise chain, you must *promisify* it. Libraries like bluebird have helpers for promisification.

Comment: The thing is that the first promise and the last one are not related with parameters or callbacks. The first one just needs to wait until the first promise is finished no matter what is the result.

Comment: nonPromiseRelatedFuntion does not return or contain promise or anything asynchronous.

Comment: Well then I don't know what your question is. Just call the function whenever you want, where is the issue with that?

Comment: I just don't want to have empty then and catch blocks.

Comment: If you want to catch an error in a promise chain, you need a `.catch()`, period. But don't need the empty `.then()` before that, though. Why does that not look like a good solution to you? It does what it says.

Comment: @Tomalak yes sounds like I will keep it that way and include some just an info console call in the catch statement. Thanks guys.

Comment: In normal (synchronous) code, you would write a try/catch with an empty catch block as well if you want to ignore an error in a function. It's the same here, no need to overthink it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the desired flow is:

`Promise > Function > Promise`

On which the function is executed no matter the outcome of the first promise, you can simply do something like:

```js
function secondFunction(outcome) {
  // do stuff
  
  return funtionReturnsPromise2()
}

functionReturnsPromise().then(secondFunction).catch(secondFunction)
```

Now, on another topic, I would not call the second function 'unrelated' since it clearly, according to your explanation, needs to be called after the first promise is fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `nonPromiseRelatedFuntion` is sync and you're not interested in return value of `functionReturnsPromise`

```
functionReturnsPromise()
.then(
  // no matter what happens, the function is invoked
  () => { nonPromiseRelatedFunction() },
  error => { 
    nonPromiseRelatedFunction()
    // do error handling from functionReturnsPromise
  } 
)
.then(() => functionReturnsPromise2() }
.catch(console.error)
```

If you need a value:

```
functionReturnsPromise()
.then(
  value => {
    nonPromiseRelatedFunction()
    return functionReturnsPromise2(value)
  },
  error => { 
    nonPromiseRelatedFunction()
    // do error handling from functionReturnsPromise
  } 
)
.catch(console.error) // error handling from functionReturnsPromise2
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers I'm assuming

- nonPromiseRelatedFunction is synchronous
- you really don't care about any return values
- nonPromiseRelatedFunction **and** funtionReturnsPromise2 should be executed in all circumstances

> Having read **ALL** the comments to the question, I see the above is not an assumption after all

The simplest solution is to get rid of the first `.then`

```
funtionReturnsPromise()
    .catch(()=>{})
    .then(()=>{
        nonPromiseRelatedFuntion()
    })
    .then(()=>{
        return funtionReturnsPromise2()
    })
```

Note: such code could be written

```
funtionReturnsPromise()
    .catch(()=>{})
    .then(nonPromiseRelatedFuntion)
    .then(funtionReturnsPromise2)
```

sure, the last two functions will receive arguments, but if the code in those functions ignores arguments anyway, then their will be no issue